# アーカイブからイベントログの詳細情報を取得

Tags: windows, powershell

すみません。Windows2012Serverで、
イベントログのアーカイブファイルからイベントログの詳細情報を取得したいと思っています。
 取得したい情報は、
Get-EventLog -ComputerName 192.168.63.1 -LogName "Security" -After '2016/1/1' -Before '2016/2/1' | Select-Object EntryType,EventID,Source,TimeGenerated,Message | Where-Object {$_.EventID -in 4624,4778}

を実行したときのように下記の情報がほしいです。
 １．日時、Source
２．Message
３．イベントID
４．サブジェクト
 ・セキュリティID
・アカウント名：
・アカウントドメイン
 ・ログオンID
５．ログオンタイプ
６．新しいログオン
 ・セキュリティID
・アカウント名：
・アカウントドメイン
 ・ログオンID
・ログオンGUID
７．プロセス情報
・プロセスID
・プロセス名
 ８．ネットワーク情報
・ワークステーション名: ACTSYS-ACT1B
・ソース ネットワーク アドレス
 ・ソース ポート
９．詳細な認証情報
・ログオンプロセス
 ・認証パッケージ
 ・移行されたサービス
 ・パッケージ名 (NTLM のみ)
・キーの長さ
 ーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
（例）
EntryType : SuccessAudit
 EventID : 4624
 Source : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
 TimeGenerated : 2016/03/01 15:51:00
 Message : アカウントが正常にログオンしました。
            サブジェクト:
                セキュリティ ID:        S-1-0-0
                アカウント名:        -
                アカウント ドメイン:        -
                ログオン ID:        0x0

```
        ログオン タイプ:            3

        偽装レベル:        %%1833　　（これはなくてもいいです）

        新しいログオン:
            セキュリティ ID:        S-1-5-21-3598203821-372466494
            アカウント名:        nana
            アカウント ドメイン:        A-AC2B
            ログオン ID:        0x572e5efe
            ログオン GUID:        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000

        プロセス情報:
            プロセス ID:        0x0
            プロセス名:        -

        ネットワーク情報:
            ワークステーション名:    MA-PC2
            ソース ネットワーク アドレス:    -
            ソース ポート:        -

        詳細な認証情報:
            ログオン プロセス:        NtLmSsp
            認証パッケージ:    NTLM
            移行されたサービス:    -
            パッケージ名 (NTLM のみ):    NTLM V1
            キーの長さ:        128
```

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

しかし
get-winevent -path 'C:\Event-Backup\Archive-Security-2016-01-27-11-29-40-032.evtx' -filterxpath "*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4624 or EventID=4778) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='2016-01-05T15:00:00.000Z' and @SystemTime<='2016-01-27T14:59:59.999Z']]]"

だと、
TimeCreated Id LevelDisplayName Message

2016/01/02 8:59:39 4624 情報 アカウントが正常にログオンしました。...
2016/01/02 8:49:39 4624 情報 アカウントが正常にログオンしました。...

と、
 １．日時とSource
２．ログオン
３．イベントID
の情報しか取得できず、どうすればそれ以外の情報も取得できますでしょうか。
もしわかれば教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すみません。下記で何とか解決しそうです。失礼しました。

get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{path='C:\Event-Backup\Archive-Security-2016-01-27-11-29-40-032.evtx'; logname="Security"; id = (4778,4624); starttime = '2016-01-25T15:00:00.000Z'; endtime = '2016-01-31T14:59:59.999Z' }  | select *